# Extend _engine in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

Seems I not understand some fundamental in javascript,

I have the following code:

```
Raphael.fn.group = function() {
    var out = Raphael._engine.group(this);
    this.__set__ && this.__set__.push(out);
    return out;
};
(window.Raphael.svg &&
function(e) {
    e.group = function(svg) {
        //Want this to be called $ function defined in Raphael._engine 
        // as var $=function(..){..}
        // line 3780
        var el = $("g");
        svg.canvas && svg.canvas.appendChild(el);
        var res = new Element(el, svg);
        res.type = "group";
        return res;
    }
})(window.Raphael._engine);
var paper = Raphael("out", 800, 600);
//test with circle;
paper.circle(100, 100, 50);
//test with new method;
paper.group();​
```

So I found that $ near commented line got from global scope, not from Raphael._engine scope, is here any way to extend _engine, or I should to patch raphael to do such things ?

http://jsfiddle.net/YV2SR/4/

[more simple jsfiddle - without raphael at all](http://jsfiddle.net/xMfZK/1/)

Comment: NM. Saw the simpler example. No. var anything = 'stuff' inside an object constructor is equivalent to a private property in other languages.

Comment: $ is defined as var of anonymous function, which property test1 of uses , what i want to know - if it possible to get pointer to $ defined in that anonymous function, without change "do not edit area"

Comment: You would have to also define $ as this.$ IN AN OBJECT to expose it.

Comment: That I understand, I not understand the following - can i get $ without editing 3rdparty library ?

Comment: No, it's an internal var of another object. You would have to expose it.

Comment: And there is no way to expose it from any external function ?  To sad :(

Comment: Edit. Never mind. I understand what you were saying there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, one last edit.

No, you can't get `var $` defined inside an object constructor without altering that source code to expose $ somehow. That's the JavaScript equivalent of a private property.

Comment: $ is not jQuery, it is defined in rafael.js, i not want to make it global, I want to know if there is way to use variables from scope where they defined

Comment: I explained JS scope but in this case if Raphael defined $ globally without making it accessible from _engine, I assume they had a reason to do that (probably a not-very-good-one). To use $ out of that scope without it being global you would have to assign $ function as this.$ inside the engine constructor to make it public.

Comment: Raphael not defined $ globally, so I need to patch raphael and make 
`this.$=$` after `$` declaration ? no way to switch context/scope  ?
 also 'g' is valid tag, inside 'sgf' tag :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Usage of 'scope' threw me. You can use 'call' and 'apply' to do that. I'll add an example.

Comment: still not helps, I tried http://jsfiddle.net/YV2SR/7/ the $ still  called from global context, so it is not defined by rafael, the question, is can i get reference to $ which defined in raphael.js on line 3780 without changing raphael.js code ?

Comment: I will try to make simpler example, without raphael to  just show what i need.

Comment: When you use call like that, the method is fired as if it is a property of the object in the first argument.

Comment: No, but I could have used in the context of your example for clarity. See my edit. It should fire as if a property of e which is ._engine

Comment: check my last jsfiddle, can you make it work as i expecting, i tried use $.call(T,2) but it not working, still return null.